# Python take the last number of each line in a text file and make it into a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, text

I just want the last number of each line.

```
with open(home + "/Documents/stocks/" + filePath , newline='') as f:
stockArray = (line.split(',') for line in f.readlines())
    for line in stockArray:
        List = line.pop()
        #print(line.pop())
        #print(', '.join(line))
else:
    print("Finished")
```

I tried using the line.pop() to take the last element but it only takes it from one line? How can I get it from each line and store it in list?

Answer (score 6):

You probably just want something like:

```
last_col = [line.split(',')[-1] for line in f]
```

For more complicated csv files, you might want to look into the `csv` module in the standard library as that will properly handle quoting of fields, etc.

Comment: This will include the newline in each value.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = []
with open(home + "/Documents/stocks/" + filePath , newline='') as f:
    for line in f:
        my_list.append(line[-1]) # adds the last character to the list
```

That should do it.

If you want to add the last element of a list from the file:

```
my_list = []
with open(home + "/Documents/stocks/" + filePath , newline='') as f:
    for line in f:
        my_list.append(line.split(',')[-1]) # adds the last character to the list
```